# How do I enter a multi-line footnote in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

My intuition was

```
Lorem ipsum\footnote{long footnote
  that spans a whole
  bunch of
  lines.
}
```

But regardless of where I put the `{` and `}` in relation to the footnote text, I get the following error:

```
Latex Error: ./mydoc.tex:142 Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:― not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Footnotes are filled in the available space just like any other paragraph: you just write

```
\footnote{ 
    a whole lot of text that goes on and on and on and...
    ...
    and may consists of multiple sentences. But after a while
    ... 
    it finally comes to a stop.
}
```

That is not your problem. Looking at the error message (which I don't recognize from personal experience), I'd say your problem is character set or font related.

Is you editor using unicode?

Comment: it was a random UTF-8 character in my footnote source -- stupid copy and paste.

Comment: Now, of course, I _want_ some unicode in my document and I can't seem to get it.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

The error you're getting indicates there's a coding setup issue.  Googling the error message suggests you may be running TexShop, or you need to install latex unicode support.  use

```
apt-get latex-ucs
```

or something similar and try it again.

Answer (score 1):

I get this error a lot when I cut text from another document and paste into LaTeX. My plain text editor doesn't warn me that I pasted in some bad character. Although it is tedious, you can

- comment out the entire text of your footnote, replace it by XX, and confirm that now your document runs
- retype the entire text of your footnote by hand.

This always works for me. As a shortcut, you may be able to see a punctuation mark that is the culprit and simply fix that.

In the example you gave, it looks like maybe you got an em-dash character that needs to be replaced by the standard LaTeX construction of two or three hyphens.